# CreateDir function not working under Windows 8.1 with Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create a folder programmatically in Delphi 10 Seattle with `CreateDir` function.
The code compiles, runs but does not do anything. Run as admin didn't  workout too.

I am trying to create directory like `D:\A\B` While `A` folder does not exist.
Is there a way to create both folders?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: if not DirectoryExists (MyDir) then Begin
  CreateDir(MyDir);
End;

Comment: I am trying to create directory like D:\A\B
While A folder does not exist.
Is there a way to create both folders

Comment: The answer is then given by @DavidHeffernan in his third point. Create the A folder first, then the B folder.

Comment: @user8886360 you can't create `B` until `A` is created first. `CreateDir()` only creates the last leaf folder, it does not create missing intermediate folders. `ForceDirectories()` does that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple function such as:

```
 function TForm1.createfolders(Const FolderName: String): Boolean;
begin
  If Not ForceDirectories(FolderName) then
    ShowMessage('Unable to create folder - '+FolderName)
  else
    Result := True;
end;
```

If you call it attempting to create an invalid folder you'll get a message, for example the following fails;

```
 CreateFolders('C:\Windows\something'); // Returns an error
```

Whereas, this works;

```
CreateFolders('C:\Something\something'); // Creates folders
```

The function returns true is successful or false if it fails.

The error checking for *ForceDirectories* is minimal, either it worked or it didn't. No further information is provided, in which case you should use David's solution using the API.

Comment: `CreateFolders('C:\Windows\something');` would not fail if the user is an admin with write access to the `Windows` folder.

Comment: You are probably correct @remylebeau. I have admin rights on my laptop, and it did fail. That's not to say I have full rights, Microsoft are funny like that. :)

Answer (score 9):

To create a directory with parent directories at once, e.g. `D:\A\B\C` if `D:\A` does not exist yet, you can use:

```
function ForceDirectories(Dir: string): Boolean;
```

located in System.SysUtils unit, explained here:
[ForceDirectories](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.ForceDirectories)

e.g.

```
 if not DirectoryExists('D:\A\B\C')
   then ForceDirectories('D:\A\B\C');
```

This code will create folder 'C' and all missing parent folders.

Comment: Without an explanation, this answer is lacking.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the obvious failure modes:

- Insufficient permissions.
- invalid filename, e.g. using reserved characters like `?` and `*`.
- The parent directory for your path does not exist. That is if you wish to create `D:\A\B` then you must create `D:\A` first, and then `D:\A\B`.

Use the Windows API `CreateDirectory` directly and you will be able to write error checking code to let the system tell you what is wrong.